# Is the geocoding service changed?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

We are using the Google Maps API method `getLocations()` for geocoding addresses the user supplies. This used to work (up until yesterday) using only street names like "Drottninggatan". But as of today, that method returns error 602 instead of an array of possible matches.

Did Google change anything yesterday, or what else have happened? We've checked our own code and nothing new is deployed since the 7th of April.

EDIT:
We are using v2 for this service, but another where we've upgraded to v3 has the same problem

EDIT2:
I created an issue on Google with this - please star it there if you want the issue to get attention [Google Maps Issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3257)

Comment: Are you using the V2 or the v3 api?

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/35259d0051589b5b

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-API/browse_thread/thread/0f7887c52f151a11

Comment: it would appear 


groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api  might be the place to ask/look.....

Comment: We are using v2 for this service, but another where we've upgraded to v3 has the same problem

Comment: @Mitch: Thanks for the links, but they deal with routing, not pure geocoding unfortunately

Comment: I've noticed the same thing. Just providing the user's address now returns a google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS, but if the user further clarifies their location with a city/state/ect then the location is found with no problem. This was working without the further clarification as of last week.

Comment: @Craig: Good to hear it's not only me! :-) I found that using a smaller part of the street name works better. I.e. "Drottning" yields better results than the complete "Drottninggatan". Very strange...

Comment: Well we are having similar issues, I just tried the smaller part of the street name idea out and that is working... So something like 123 ABC works, while 123 ABC St or 123 ABC Street doesn't, unless the city is specified as well. Something strange is going on.

Comment: @Crag: Did you star the issue on Google?

Comment: I did, even though I'm still not entirely sure we are having the same issue.

Comment: Seems more people are now having (or just now noticing) this issue. The Google Maps Issue has a few more people who have starred it, and there are a few newer comments.

Comment: @Niklas I'm no longer able to reproduce the error. Every case that caused an error to occur now properly works. No idea what google changed to make it work again, because they haven't said a word on the issue page created for this problem, but for me it seems to be fixed. Can you comment on if the issue has been fixed for you?

Comment: @Crag: that sounds amazing! I've been away from the office a few days, but will test on Monday.

Comment: It seems to be working for me too! Will test more to verify, but it surely looks promising.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but this happened again. I have code requestion the lat/long values as `result[0].geometry.location.Ua` and `result[0].geometry.location.Va` but they changed it so `.Ua` is now `.Ta` and `.Va` is `.Ua`. Crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, Google seem to have resolved this issue.